# How come object syntax is same as function syntax in TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Code is taken from [`TS Generic section`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content)

Below are 2 TS generic function and an object with generic function,

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}
 
let myIdentity: <Type>(arg: Type) => Type = identity;
```

and

```
interface GenericIdentityFn {
  <Type>(arg: Type): Type;
}
```

and

```
interface GenericFnInObj {
    fn: <T>(arg: T) => T
}
```

How first two types are same, According to my understanding first one is a generic function which takes any type of arg and will return same value so return same type.

But second is an object which has a property which is a generic function.

and Third a is an object which has a property named as `fn` which we can call it as: `obj.fn()`

Is this related to fact that `functions` in JS is an `object`.

Comment: "_But second is an object which has a property which is a generic function_": This is not quite right: that syntax indicates that the type is [callable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) (according to the specified signature). Notice that there's no property/method name for the call signature — which means that it applies to the type itself ([example](https://tsplay.dev/mxEE8W)).

Comment: Could you please highlight an explicit question in the body of the post, preferably with a question mark? And rephrase so instead of "here are two things, and a second and a third thing" and referring to them by position, could you be explicit about which pieces of which things you're talking about? The indirection is making this hard to follow. Presumably you're just confused about what a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) is, and how it differs from a method. (If so then @jsejcksn can write an answer). But it's not clear right now.